# golang gmbapi service businessprofileperformance on GetDailyMetricsTimeSeries returning Error 404: Requested entity was not found

Tags: go, google-my-business-api

I construct the service passing a CredentialsFile and the Scope for auth, then I call the GetDailyMetricsTimeSeries with the right name (locations/{location_id}) but returns error 404.

> 

```
        ctx := context.Background()
    performanceService, err := businessprofileperformance.NewService(ctx,
        option.WithCredentialsFile("client_secret.json"),
        option.WithScopes(Scope))
    if err != nil {
        log.Println(err.Error())
        return
    }
    cm := performanceService.Locations.GetDailyMetricsTimeSeries("locations/12345...")
    cm.DailyMetric("WEBSITE_CLICKS")
    cm.DailyRangeStartDateYear(2022)
    cm.DailyRangeStartDateMonth(6)
    cm.DailyRangeStartDateDay(1)

    cm.DailyRangeEndDateYear(2022)
    cm.DailyRangeEndDateMonth(12)
    cm.DailyRangeEndDateDay(30)
    response, err := cm.Do()
    if err != nil {
        log.Println(err.Error())
        return
    }
    if c := response.HTTPStatusCode; c >= 200 || c <= 299 {
        j, _ := response.MarshalJSON()
        log.Println(j)
    }
```

my client_secret.json file is like this

> 

```
{
    "type": "",
    "project_id": "",
    "private_key_id": "",
    "private_key": "",
    "client_email": "",
    "client_id": "",
    "auth_uri": "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth",
    "token_uri": "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token",
    "auth_provider_x509_cert_url": "https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/certs",
    "client_x509_cert_url": ""
}
```

I think the problem is missing the subject param for the location_id reference, but I didn't found where I can pass it
I've hide the personal information of json file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the problem was in the authentication, the subject was missing, so I managed it this way:

```
func (a *AppCredential) GetCredentials(ctx context.Context, scope string) (*google.Credentials, error) {
jsonFile, err := os.Open("config/client_secret.json")
if err != nil {
    log.Println("error oppening json")
    return &google.Credentials{}, err
}
defer jsonFile.Close()
jsonData, _ := ioutil.ReadAll(jsonFile)
creds, err := google.CredentialsFromJSONWithParams(ctx, jsonData, google.CredentialsParams{Scopes: []string{scope}, Subject: "account@email.com"})
if err != nil {
    return &google.Credentials{}, err
}
return creds, nil
```

}

then

```
ctx := context.Background()
creds, err := appCreds.GetCredentials(ctx, "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/business.manage")
if err != nil {
    log.Println(err.Error())
    return
}
performanceService, err := businessprofileperformance.NewService(ctx, option.WithCredentials(creds))
if err != nil {
    log.Println(err.Error())
    return
}
cm := performanceService.Locations.GetDailyMetricsTimeSeries("locations/{location_id}")
response, err := cm.Do()
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you please verify through a get locations call that the GBP location still exists and that you have access to it?

GET [https://mybusinessbusinessinformation.googleapis.com/v1/{parent=accounts/*}/locations](https://mybusinessbusinessinformation.googleapis.com/v1/%7Bparent=accounts/*%7D/locations)

404 could indicate that the GBP location was removed.

Comment: I'm not passing "locations/12345...", this was an example